# How to get mac address of client in node js?

Tags: node.js, nginx, networking, mac-address

Is it possible to get mac address from the incoming request object?
My application is gonna be used locally on the same subnet and it runs behind a nginx proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tool that accesses the ARP table (a table that contains MAC addresses of IPs in your local network). Something like this [arp-lookup package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@network-utils/arp-lookup). You can extract the incoming request ip. Then use this IP to extract the MAC address with the arp-lookup.

The code would be something like this:

```js
const{ toMAC } = require('@network-utils/arp-lookup');

// ...

async function handleIncomingRequest( req, res ) {
    const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    const mac = await toMAC(ip);

    // do stomething with the MAC address...
}
```